# How to properly configure a custom error page

Tags: laravel

I have a WebController where I have this route:

```
Route::get('/error/{errorCode}', 'WebController@error')->name('error');
```

And in the error() method I would like to configure the content of the respective page to show the error code, a title, etc like:

```
public function error($errorCode)
    {
        $error = new \stdClass();
        $error->code = $errorCode;
        $error->title = "Content is not available";


        return view('error', [
            'error' => $error
        ]);
    }
```

Error.blade.php

```
    @extends('master')
    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
       <p>{{ $error->code }}</p>
       <h1>{{ $error->title }}</h1>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

However, if I access a page that doesn't exist for example it appears a default 404 page and not the error view. Do you know what is necessary to correctly use the created error view instead of the default page?

Comment: you will check existance of the first. If it doesn't exist then you will through your own error message.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain better?

Comment: Search laravel errors pages, you will find some of them. You will need to publish those error pages which are hidden by default. So then you customize those pages

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `render()` method of Laravel exception handler:
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Exceptions/Handler.php

And use this exception checker to return your view:

```
if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException)
{
    return response()->view('errors', ['code' => 404], 404);
}
```

You can handle other codes too.

Comment: Thanks, but like that, accessing a page that doesnt exist it appears http error 500.

Comment: The 500 error is a server error, it means that you have to debug and find the error on your code. Something like syntax error or other framework errors. Everything can be handled inside this Handler class.

Comment: Thanks but that 500 error appears using that checker instead of the default when accessing a page that doesn't exist. With the default render() method that 500 error dont appear but it appears the default 404 page instead of the error view.

Comment: Have you checked your log file?